# ServiceConnection called after I used object of bound service class and I got NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I am doing music player but I have problem in my service connection when I want to bind with the service the object of Service class get null pointer exception and I tried startService and bind in onCreate() and onStart () method sill I have problem I don't know why?

second problem I used content provider here but I did not get same song that I clicked list item  in previous activity  which contains list activity

Comment: Could you please post the logcat messages?

Comment: sorry about that I will try put picture of it

Comment: What's 234th line code?Please check it.

Comment: boundService.playSong(); inside this     public void songPicked(int index) {

Comment: if you look at the Log.d() you will see the onStart() method running then the method songPicked( ) then Service connection rather than ServiceConnection run second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try moving your `songPicked(index)` code inside `onServiceConnected()` and see if this helps. I think in `onStart()`, even before the service is bound, `songPicked(index)` is getting executed and hence `boundService` will be null resulting in NPE. It may take some time for the service to bind and hence moving your code to `onServiceConnected()` callback will ensure `boundService` won't be `null`.

Comment: thanks Suhas now it is working thank you  but how I get same data that between two activities in content providre